# Python accepts non-existing files

Tags: python, file-not-found

After many modifications, this error still bugs me.I have an assignment, part of which is to read in by input filenames of existing files on the computer until the user enters a filename of a file which doesn't exist.That part of my program looks like this:

```
import os.path
file_lst=[]
f=True  

while f:
    tx=input("Unesite file path:")
    if os.path.isfile(tx):
        file_lst.append(tx)

    else:
        print("Broken.")
        f=False

print(file_lst)
```

The `print("Broken.")` statement is there to check whether the loop actually breaks.The program runs it like this:It accepts the first input, which is an existing file, then I enter a non-existing file, after which the loop breaks and the `file_lst`is printed out.However,the program then asks again for the file input(which is not located anywhere in the rest of the code).When I enter a non-existent file,the program stops and prints out FileNotFoundError(the error is located somewhat later in the file where I am opening files).The error screen looks like this:

```
Unesite file path:\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\Desktop\primer.txt
Unesite file path:f
Broken.
['\\\\vmware-host\\Shared Folders\\Desktop\\primer.txt']
Unesite file path:g
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "//vmware-host/Shared Folders/Desktop/VDZ_3.py", line 25, in  <module>
f=open(tx,"r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g'
```

Here is where FileNotFoundError occurs:

```
if len(file_lst)==0:
    print("Nema unetih imena fajlova.")
else:
    for tx in file_lst:
        tx=input("Unesite file path:")
        f=open(tx,"r")
```

I can't find a rational explanation for this, so I wrote this out to be, hopefully,enlightened.I work in Python 3.6.3 on vmware-host(windows 7 emulator) on MacBook.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: before opening the file you throw away `tx` and read it again using `input()`, which is not checked to exist.

Comment: What is the actual question here? The first part seems like you're describing  a phantom `while` loop that you haven't posted, but the second part could be a description of simply running the program a second time and giving it an invalid input instead of a valid one

Comment: The while loop is in the first code section of the text.The point of the invalid input is to check whether the loop properly functions, because the assignment demands that the user enter filenames until he enters a non-existent one.